# Can't remove the last item in list, [-1] isnt working?

Tags: python

Line 30:  'new_2.remove(new_2[-1])'  this is meant to remove the last letter in the list (which will be the 's' at the end, because I want to remove the 's' when the number before it is '1', because, y'know, grammar. But it removes the first 's' even though I'm having it remove the last item by doing [-1]. Everything else is working but I dont know why it's removing the last 's' and not the first one?!

```
import random
import time
will = ['No', 'Yes', 'Maybe', 'Probably not', 'Probably', 'Definitely not', 'Definitely']

time_1 = ['1']
time_2 = ['days', 'seconds', 'years', 'weeks', 'minutes', 'months'] 

def listToString(str_in): 
    str1 = "" 
    for x in str_in: 
        str1 += x    
    return str1


print("Enter a question starting\nwith 'when' or 'will' to shake 8 ball\n"
'0 to exit\n')

while True:
  kb_in = input(': ').lower().strip()
  print('\nShaking...\n')
  time.sleep(0.6)
  if kb_in == '0':
    print('bye'); exit()
  elif 'when' in kb_in:
    new = random.choice(time_1)
    if new == '1':
      print(new, end = ' ')
      new_1 = random.choice(time_2)
      new_2 = list(new_1)
      new_2.remove(new_2[-1])  # not taking last 's' out of 'seconds' ??
      print(listToString(new_2), '\n')
    else:
      print(f'{new} {random.choice(time_2)}\n')
  elif 'will' in kb_in and 'when' not in kb_in:
    print(random.choice(will))
  else:
    print("\nInput does not contain 'will' or 'when'\n")
```

Comment: You're not telling it to remove the last letter. You're telling it to remove an `'s'`.

Comment: Python can't tell what index that "s" is in. It just gets the last element and removes whatever that value is. Just do `del new_2[-1]` or something like that.

Comment: `list.remove` is one of the built-in methods that seems like a good idea but is almost always the wrong choice. `list.index` is a similar case.

Comment: You can remove the last element from a list with `del lst[-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

`list.remove` removes the first occurrence of a value.

So to achieve what you want, you could replace

`new_2.remove(new_2[-1])`

with

`new_2 = new_2[:-1]`

That will slice the list up to the penultimate value.

You could also do

`new_2.pop()`

which will remove the last value of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code does not work is because `new_2[-1]` returns `'s'`, and that line of codes deletes the first matching element, so if you use that line of code on list `['s','e','c','o','n','d','s']`, and then print it out, you will get `'seconds'`

You can just use this code to remove the last letter from the word:

```
  new_2.pop()
```

or

```
  new_2.pop(len(new_2) - 1)
```

This code simply removes the last element of the list using the `pop` method since `len(new_2) - 1` is the index of the final element.

Answer (score 0):

This may also be a good place to employ regular expressions.

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"s$", "", "days")
'day'
```

This matches an `'s'` at the end of the string (denoted by `$` in the regex).

We could also handle cases where there is whitespace after the `'s'` by using `\s` (the whitespace token) and matching it zero or more times with `\s*`.

```py
>>> re.sub(r"s\s*$", "", "days   ")
'day'
```